# What's going on in this function?

Tags: shell-script, function

```
log ()
{
  A=$1
  print "`date '+%m/%d/%y  %H:%M:%S'`: $A"  >> LOGFILE.txt
  print "$A"
}
```

This is how log function used in most of the shell scripts in our environment.
and it's been used in script like below:

```
if ["blah" != "0"]
then
log "not a zero value"
fi
```

How does the log function work when the if condition is satisfied?

Can you explain what each line means inside the log function?

Comment: `print` is not a standard command.

Answer (score 3):

It would help if you note that you're using `ksh` or `zsh` - they both have a `print` shell built-in.

```
  1. A=$1
  2. print "`date '+%m/%d/%y  %H:%M:%S'`: $A"  >> LOGFILE.txt
  3. print "$A"
```

Line 1: $1 means "first argument to function log()". So, assign value of first argument to `log` to variable named "A".

Line 2: The "grave accents" (a.k.a. "back tics") mean "run the enclosed command and substite its output for the back-tic'ed string. $A means "the value of variable named "A"". So, compose a string by running `date`, and interpolate the value of `A`. Shells typically distinguish between rvalue (name assigned to) and lvalue (contents of variable. The ">>" means put it on the end of a file named "LOGFILE".

Line 3: Just write value of variable named "A" to stdout.

The `log` function is a pretty common way of doing sh-script logging: write one copy of any message to a file with a date stamp, write one copy to stdout. The sh-script runs in a terminal window, and messages just scroll by, but also appear in a file for later debugging.

You invocation of `log` in the true-clause of the if-statement passes the entire string "not a zero value" as the first formal argument of function `log`. That's what value gets assigned to variable "A" in line 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
A=$1
```

assigns the first function argument to the variable A

```
print "`date '+%m/%d/%y  %H:%M:%S'`: $A"  >> LOGFILE.txt
```

prints the date and the value of variable A and appends it to LOGFILE.txt

```
print "$A"
```

prints the first function argument

BTW, in the line:
    if ["blah" != "0"]

There should be space after `[` and before `]`, like this:

```
if [ "blah" != "0" ]
```

BTW, the print is not a standard command in some shells.